# How to run Lambda functions in parallel with individual retries and only update final state once all complete successfully?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I need to orchestrate multiple jobs in parallel (each using Lambdas in AWS), ensure all finish by retrying individual jobs as needed, and then update a state only when all jobs have completed successfully. It will look like this:

[image: Example]

This image was taken from the [Step Functions documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-parallel-state.html). I'm considering whether Step Functions might be an answer.

Any thoughts on how this might look using Lambda (with or without Step Functions)? I'm guessing deadletter queues might be involved to facilitate retries? My biggest unknown is how to update the final state only after all jobs complete and considering whether retries may have occurred.

Comment: "Multiple jobs in parallel": Is there a single record per execution (i.e. multiple "lookups" tasks, but for just one "user")? Or does each execution have multiple "user" records, each requiring the multiple "lookup" tasks to be performed?

Comment: @fedonev I'm not sure I understand the question. Each worker will be querying a third-party API for different aspects of data within the same overarching account.

Comment: I was trying to elicit which of Sfn's two flavours of do-multiple-things-at-once applies.  The [Parallel](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-parallel-state.html) State sends a single payload down multiple task branches.  The [Map](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-map-state.html) State sends multiple payloads (= elements of an array) down a single branch.

Answer (score 1):

You are correctly, using AWS Step Functions do resolve your problem.

But, as you are looking for other approaches using pure lambda you will need a state persistence, as the lambda doesn't have that over different functions.

1. Create a data structure that will be checked at the end of each lambda execution, e.g boolean attributes that corresponds to each process that have to be executed
2. At the end of each process (lambda execution), change the attribute related to that lambda process to true, than verify if all the attributes are true, if yes you can invoke the lambda responsible to the next step of your pipeline.

If you need retry when errors came up, implement a DLQ and you can have more control of it.

Comment: So basically, track the states of each lambda job in sone persistent storage such as a database, keep states up to date after each job completes, and if all are true, continue the pipeline?

Comment: Exactly @ChadJohnson, you can also have other attributes to track unexpected behavior like errors and then handle as you wish.